# Mongoose findOne not working as expected on nested records

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've got a collection in MongoDB whose simplified version looks like this:

```
    Dealers = [{
    Id: 123,
    Name: 'Someone',
    Email: 'someone@somewhere.com',
    Vehicles: [
        {
            Id: 1234,
            Make: 'Honda',
            Model: 'Civic' 
        },
        {
            Id: 2345,
            Make: 'Ford',
            Model: 'Focus'
        },
        {
            Id: 3456,
            Make: 'Ford',
            Model: 'KA'
        }
    ]
}]
```

And my Mongoose Model looks a bit like this:

```
const vehicle_model = mongoose.Schema({
    Id: {
        Type: Number
    },
    Email: {
        Type: String
    },
    Vehicles: [{
        Id: {
            Type: Number
        },
        Make: {
            Type: String
        },
        Model: {
            Type: String
        }
    }]
})
```

Note the Ids are not MongoDB Ids, just distinct numbers.

I try doing something like this:

```
const response = await vehicle_model.findOne({ 'Id': 123, 'Vehicles.Id': 1234 })
```

But when I do:

```
console.log(response.Vehicles.length)
```

It's returned all the Vehicles nested records instead on the one I'm after.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: `findOne` is for finding one document and return it without manipulations. Your document contains a list of vehicles, thus, the list is returned. If you want to return only part of this list, you can use an aggregation pipeline with `$filter`

Comment: So am I right in thinking that findOne only works at a root document level. IE. It will always return the Dealer record and all it's Vehicles nested records not mater selection value I use to try and filter the Vehicles records?

Comment: Kind of?  `findOne()` matches _documents_. But try also using projection, eg `vehicle_model.findOne({ 'Id': 123, 'Vehicles.Id': 1234 }, {'Vehicles.$':1} )`.

Comment: @user20042973 nice! I was not familiar with this option for find. I think you should put it as the answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is asked very frequently. Indeed someone asked [a related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74112508/mongodb-query-on-nested-objects) just 18 minutes before this one.

When query the database you are requesting that it identify and return matching *documents* to the client. That is a separate action entirely than asking for it to transform the shape of those documents before they are sent back to the client.

In MongoDB, the latter operation (transforming the shape of the document) is usually referred to as "Projection". Simple projections, specifically just returning a subset of the fields, can be done directly in `find()` (and similar) operations. Most drivers and the shell use the second argument to the method as the projection specification, see [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection).

Your particular case is a little more complicated because you are looking to trim off some of the values in the array. There is a dedicated page in the documentation titled [*Project Fields to Return from Query*](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) which goes into more detail about different situations. Indeed near the bottom is a section titled [*Project Specific Array Elements in the Returned Array*](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#project-specific-array-elements-in-the-returned-array) which describes your situation more directly. In it is where they describe usage of the positional `$` operator. You can use that as a starting place as follows:

```
db.collection.find({
  "Id": 123,
  "Vehicles.Id": 1234
},
{
  "Vehicles.$": 1
})
```

Playground [demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vZC5fSt1Z1H).

If you need something more complex, then you would have to start exploring usage of [the `$elemMatch` (projection) operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) (*not* [the query variant](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)) or, [as @nimrod serok mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74112760/mongoose-findone-not-working-as-expected-on-nested-records?noredirect=1#comment130853716_74112760), using [the `$filter` aggregation operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in an aggregation pipeline. The last option here is certainly the most expressive and flexible, but also the most verbose.