# $elemMatch with $in SpringData Mongo Query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am in the process of attempting to create a method that will compose a query using Spring Data and I have a couple of questions. I am trying to perform a query using top level attributes of a document (i.e. the `id` field) as well as attributes of an subarray.

To do so I am using a query similar to this:

```java
db.getCollection("journeys").find({ "_id._id": "0104", "journeyDates": { $elemMatch: { "period": { $in: [ 1,2 ] } } } })
```

As you can see I would also like to filter using `$in` for the values of the subarray. Running the above query though result in wrong results, as if the `$elemMatch` is ignored completely.

Running a similiar but slightly different query like this:

```java
db.getCollection("journeys").find({ "_id._id": { $in: [ "0104" ] } }, { journeyDates: { $elemMatch: { period: { $in: [ 1, 2 ] } } } })
```

does seem to yield better results but it returns the only first found element matching the `$in` of the subarray filter.

Now my question is, how can I query using both top level attributes as well subarrays using `$in`. Preferably I would like to avoid aggregations. Secondly, how can I translate this native Mongo query to a Spring data `Query` object?

Comment: To clarify - when you say "wrong results" you're referring to the fact that all entries in the `journeyDates` array are returned? If the array is going to have more than one matching entry then I do not think you can do this today without using `$filter` in an aggregation pipeline (`$addFields` stage most likely). Some info and links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74112760/mongoose-findone-not-working-as-expected-on-nested-records/74113511#74113511) (in particular the last paragraph)

Comment: To provide some clarifications; In my use case, it is always guaranteed that the `journeyDates` subarray will always contain a single element matching the filter. So in our case `{ journeyDates: { $elemMatch: { period: { $in: [ 1, 2 ] } } } }` should have returned exactly two elements. However when trying it out, I get only one element (i.e. the last one matching) instead of both matching ones.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your response, perhaps you can update the question to include some sample documents and desired output? Is your comment saying that there will be a matching element for _each_ of the values in the `$in` list?